# Android:How to start Android Market (Play Store) and get know about closing from my own app

Tags: android, google-play

I  implemented some app that can start Play Store. This is some kind of firewall and its necessary to know where user close then  Play Store. How can I become some kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! It works. It was trivial but I could not found it of myself .

Comment: Thank you again. But I have now a little problem: my app received that Market is closed only if it really closed :-) (it means I must use Task manager or use several times of back button to close Market). Does it possible to let my app know when the user press home button by using Market (Market is then not really closed)?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I use startActivityForResult for starting of Play Store. So if Play Store is closed then my app know it. But I want let my app also known if Play Store is in background, f.e. if user press "Home-Button". Is something like that possible?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

Comment: You override onKeyDown in your activity and check for `keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME`